# Elliptic regularity - nonlinear case

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, reference-request, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Let's say I have a weak solution $u \in H^1(\Omega)$, $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open, to the equation
$$
\Delta u = e^u,
$$
let's also assume that $e^u \in L^\infty(\Omega)$.
Does it follow that $u \in C^\infty(\Omega)$?
Also, does it work if we substitute the last requirement with $e^u \in L^1(\Omega)$?

I tried to look for this kind of result on Gilbarg-Trudinger, but it was not helpful. Also M.E. Taylor's book does not deal with this case. It might be that you could do this using the Calderon-Zygmund inequality.

If anyone could give me a hint or a reference I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $e^u\in L^\infty$, then you have that $u\in C^{1,\alpha}_{loc}(\Omega)$, which implies that $u\in C^1(\Omega)$. By taking any $\Omega'$ open in $\Omega$, with $\overline{\Omega}'\subset\Omega$, you have that $u,|\nabla u|\in L^\infty(\Omega')$, hence differentiating you equation, you can conclude that $\nabla u\in C^{1,\alpha}_{loc}(\Omega)$. You can continue this bootstrap argument to conclude that $u\in C^\infty(\Omega)$.

For the case $e^u\in L^1$, I dont have idea if you can get such regularity.

All I have said here can be found in the papers of Liebermann:

Boundary regularity for solutions of degenerate elliptic equations - 1988

The natural generalizationj of the natural conditions of ladyzhenskaya and uralľtseva for elliptic equations - 1991

Comment: Nice. So, the first thing I wanted to know is that: RHS of equation $\in L^\infty$, then the solution is in $C^{1,\alpha}$, which seems to be the case. I will take a look at those papers, thanks.

Comment: Also @second, if your domain is regular in the boundary, then you can conclude more, for instance, $u\in C^{1,\alpha}(\overline{\Omega})$.

Comment: I think that Theorem 2, page 1, in [here](http://math.stanford.edu/~lms/256a-12-13/pdebk/lec19.pdf) might be of some help in the case in which we have $L^2$-ness of the RHS, so that we conclude $L^\infty$-ness of the RHS. Does it help? Maybe there is a less complicated way to see it... And I'm really only concerned about interior regularity.

Comment: @Second, you need more. You need that $e^u\in L^q$ with $q>\frac{N}{2}$. It depende on the dimesion. If your function satisfies it, I agree with you that you can use the same argument. Also take a look on this post, it is a generalization of the link you have send me. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262179/boundedness-of-solutions-to-p-laplace-equation

Comment: yes, I have that (btw, I'm doing it in 2d) :D That's very nice. I think those two papers are a bit too much, do you know any simpler approach? My equation is uniformly elliptic, so I would expect some simpler proof to go from $L^\infty \to C^{1,\alpha}$...

Comment: Do you have any boundary condition?

Comment: No, I have no boundary condition. But we can restrict to the case, let's say, $\Omega$ is an open disk of radius 2, $u$ solves the equation, is in $L^\infty$, and I want to prove smoothness in the open disk (with the same center) of radius 1 (if that is of any help).

Comment: To prove regularity is always a hard task. I think you could try to show that $u\in H^2$, which implies that $u\in C$ and then bootstrap. If you have Brezis book of functional Analysis, in chapter 9 there is an outline for what I am saying.

Comment: In the last comment I have assumed that you are workin in 2d.

Answer (score 3):

$e^u\in L^\infty$ gives $u\in C^\alpha_{loc}$ (see Gilbarg-Trudinger, for instance). Then,
$\Delta u\in C^\alpha_{loc}$.
Thus, $u\in C^{2,\alpha}_{loc}$ (Gilbarg-Trudinger again). And now, the bootstrap argument gives you $u\in C^\infty$.